# Precedence of !define and /D - How can I set an overridable default value?

Tags: nsis

I'm building an installer for a system that is generally installed by my coworkers, but several things can vary from one target machine to the next, including the locations of the files-to-be-installed on the compiling machine. I thought I could set a ["gflag"](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/!define) in the source (with `!define`) and override it in the call to `makensis.exe` (with `/D`), but I can't even get my installer to recognize that a `/D` flag was passed.

More relevant documentation is behind the `/h` flag:

```
PS C:\> &"C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\makensis.exe" /h
Usage:
  makensis [ option | script.nsi | - ] [...]

Options:
  #...
  /Ddefine[=value] defines the symbol "define" for the script [to value]
  #...
```

I'm using this NSIS code:

```
!ifndef test
    !define test Foo
!endif

Section
    DetailPrint "${test}"
SectionEnd
```

I compile the installer in PowerShell:

```
&"C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\makensis.exe" "C:\path\to\test.nsi" /Dtest=Bar
```

Among the output, I see this:

```
Command line defined: "test=Bar"
```

The installer is successfully created, but it prints `Foo` while it should print `Bar`. If I comment `!define test Foo`, I get a warning when compiling:

```
1 warning:
  unknown variable/constant "{test}" detected, ignoring (C:\Mach4\Installer\test.nsi:6)
```

And then `${test}` is printed, indicating that the gflag has no value. Why does it not have a value of `Bar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line is parsed in order. In your case that means the script is parsed before `/Dtest=Bar` is parsed. Try this instead:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\makensis.exe" /Dtest=Bar "C:\path\to\test.nsi"
```